# Progressbar showing different Styles

Tags: wpf, animation

I have two solutions targeting the same 4.5 framework. Both projects uses the same version of dlls. But one is showing a progressbar without any effect. I just copied and pasted the code from one to another. One is with glossy effect and having animations in it but another is just static. What's wrong with it?

```
<ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="3,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF007B00" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="176" Opacity="0.9" BorderThickness="0" Value="80">
    <ProgressBar.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFBABABA" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFC7C7C7" Offset="0.014"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFE63B09" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </ProgressBar.Background>
</ProgressBar>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about showing some relevant code? If the markup for showing your progress bar is identic in both projects perhaps one of the projects uses a different default style for progress bars. Search your projects for the string `TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}"` or whatever type you are using and see if you come up with any default style somewhere.

Comment: <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="3,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF007B00" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="176" Opacity="0.9" BorderThickness="0" Value="80">
                <ProgressBar.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFBABABA" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFC7C7C7" Offset="0.014"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFE63B09" Offset="1"/>